# use PHPMailer to send a newsletter (multiple masked recipients without BCC)

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to use PHPMailer to send out a newsletter to 1000 or so recipients.  I currently am using addBCC to add each address, in a loop.  The newsletter sends fine, but when I my subscribers receive it, the "to" field shows the address I set as a filler, not their own address.

I am considering changing to code like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom('info@domain.com', 'Domain.com');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail2->MsgHTML($body);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $mail2 = clone $mail;
    $mail2->AddAddress($row["email"]);
    $mail2->send();
}
```

but it seems much slower and less efficient than the BCC method.  Is there a better way to send to a list, such that each user receives the email with the correct "to" address, and no access to other users' emails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to clone PHPMailer; one instance is enough. Just clear the addresses you're sending to each time around the loop.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('info@domain.com', 'Domain.com');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->msgHTML($body);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $mail->addAddress($row["email"]);
    $mail->send();
    $mail->clearAllRecipients();
}
```

You might want to also do some error checking on `send()`, and you should not be using the `mysql*` functions any more.

Comment: This answer made my day

Comment: Sorry I know this is an old thread - but I'm wanting to do the same thing as OP.

$mail->clearAllAddresses();

This function is giving me the following error when run

Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::clearAllAddresses()

Comment: Uh, so do the same thing I suggested? There's a more complete mailing list example provided with PHPMailer. Generally sending individual messages is preferable to using BCC, as it allows things like VERP addressing for better bounce handling.

Comment: @Synchro, it seems that the correct function name is: ClearAllRecipients(); not "Addresses"

Comment: Quite right, thanks, fixed. The example I mentioned is [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).